# Problem with long double in epsilon machine

Tags: c++, epsilon

I use this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main(void)
{

long double epsilon = 1;
double epsilond = 1;
float epsilonf = 1;

while (epsilon+1>1)
{
epsilon = epsilon/2;
} 
while (epsilonf + 1 > 1)
{
epsilonf = epsilonf / 2;
}
while (epsilond + 1 > 1)
{
epsilond = epsilond / 2;
}

cout.setf(ios::scientific);

cout << setprecision(20) << "\nElepsilon de la maquina long doble = " << epsilon << "\n\n";
cout << setprecision(20) << "\nElepsilon de la maquina double = " << epsilond << "\n\n";
cout << setprecision(20) << "\nElepsilon de la maquina float = " << epsilonf << "\n\n"; 
}
```

but my solution is:

```
Elepsilon de la maquina long doble = 1.11022302462515654042e-16


Elepsilon de la maquina double = 1.11022302462515654042e-16


Elepsilon de la maquina float = 5.96046447753906250000e-08
```

and double and long double is the same, for some reason im no sure of this. I see other code and the result its diferent some people get 5.xxxxx or 2.xxxx and i dont know why i get stuck in this.

Right now i using C++ in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Check if `sizeof(double)` equals `sizeof(long double)`.  That is allowed to happen.

Comment: Also, FWIW, there is [`std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) which saves you from having to calculate this.

Comment: Also note that your calculated value is `epsilon/2`: https://godbolt.org/z/Gv4G7s4xY, this produces the correct answers: https://godbolt.org/z/e55j9oqWE

Comment: In some implementations, `long double` and `double` are equivalent (usually of 64-bit precision), which seems to be your case. Live demo with MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/Pofaq384e.

Comment: On MSVC at least, `long double` is 64-bit just like `double`.

Comment: What is your platform and compiler?

Comment: @DanielLangr you have right!!! the code is right but depend where compile or the plataform i use the value change!